# Unix shell script that prints first line of any README files in directory or subdirectories

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

Anyone know how I could go about writing a unix shell script (ksh) that would print the first line of any files that match the name "README" in the current and sub directories?

Comment: By match, do you mean exactly, or just contain "README"?

Comment: You can start by checking the [`head`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/head) command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `find` with `head`

```
find . -name 'README' -exec head -1 {} \;
```

**Why `\;`?**

From [find manual](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)

> -exec command ;
>                 Execute  command; true if 0 status is returned.  All following arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until an argument
>                 consisting of `;' is encountered.  The string`{}' is replaced by the current file name being processed everywhere it occurs in  the  argu‐
>                 ments  to  the command, not just in arguments where it is alone, as in some versions of find.  Both of these **constructions might need to be
>                 escaped (with a `\') or quoted to protect them from expansion by the shell**.  See the EXAMPLES section for examples of the use of the  -exec
>                 option.   The specified command is run once for each matched file.  The command is executed in the starting directory.   There are unavoid‐
>                 able security problems surrounding use of the -exec action; you should use the -execdir option instead.

Comment: What does the \; do? Found it hard to Google those symbols. :P

Comment: @CarlinYuen to prevent shell expansion.

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need a script, just one line:

```
head -n 1 `find . -name README`
```

Answer (score 3):

```
head -1 `find . -name README`
```

Should do what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

also `find . -name README | xargs head -1`